# how to add multiple values in shared preferences and load them in recyclerview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a todo list app and want to save all todo title in the shared preference (I know it's a bad idea) but only one value is stored in the shared preference and only that loads on app restart. How to add and load multiple items from shared preference in recyclerView ?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())
        rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter
        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_APPEND)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

        fun getData():List<String>{
            val name = sharedPreferences.getString("todoName",null)
            val list = mutableListOf<String>()
            list.add(name.toString())
            return list
        }

        fun loadData(list:List<String>){
            for(item in list){
                val td = Todo(item)
                todoAdapter.addTodo(td)
            }
        }
        val data:List<String> = getData()
        loadData(data)


        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
            val todoTitle = addTodo.text.toString()
            if(todoTitle.isNotEmpty()){
                val todo = Todo(todoTitle)
                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
                editor.apply {
                    putString("todoName",todoTitle)
                    apply()
                }
            }
        }
        btnRemoveTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()

        }
    }
}
```

**Todo data class file (Todo.kt)**

```
data class Todo(
val title:String,
var isChecked: Boolean = false
)
```

**TodoAdapter.kt**

```
 import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.text.style.StrikethroughSpan
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_todo.view.*

class TodoAdapter(
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    fun addTodo(todo: Todo){
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size-1)
    }

    fun deleteDoneTodos(){
        todos.removeAll { todo ->
            todo.isChecked
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle:TextView, isChecked: Boolean){
        if(isChecked){
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }else{
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
       val currentTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            tvTodoTitle.text = currentTodo.title
            cbDone.isChecked = currentTodo.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle,currentTodo.isChecked)
            cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener{_, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle,isChecked)
                currentTodo.isChecked = !currentTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

Please take a look at code and help me out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to save in shared preferences you can convert your list to json and save then read as json and convert to list. You can use Google's Gson library for that.

```
//Save
editor.putString("todoName", Gson().toJson(list))

//Read
val list = Gson().fromJson(sharedPreferences.getString("todoName"), object: TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.javaClass)
```

But I kindly suggest you to use Room library for this kind of stuff.

official doc: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

You can use work like with Parcelable classes.

```
@Parcelize
data class ToDoKit {
    var todos: ArrayList<Todo>
}: Parcelable
```

and use SharedPreferences.Editor.putParcelable and SharedPreferences.Editor.getParcelable to operate with data.